# Efficient iteration through nested python dictionaries

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a dataset for which values determined to meet specific criteria is used to perform probability calculations as part of a summation. Currently, I hold the data in nested dictionaries to simplify the process of deterministic processing.

The algorithm I'm using proves to be very expensive and after a while overwhelms the memory.

The psudocode for the processing is as follows:

```
for businessA in business : # iterate over 77039 values 
    for businessB in business : # iterate over 77039 values
        if businessA != businessB :
            for rating in business[businessB] : # where rating is 1 - 5
                for review in business[businessB][rating] :
                    user = reviewMap[review]['user'];
                    if user in business[businessA]['users'] :
                        for users in business[businessA]['users'] :
                            # do something
                # do probability
                # a print is here
```

How can I write the above more effectively to maintain accurate probability summation for each businessA?

---

**EDIT** including source code - here, businessA and businessB are in seperate dictionaries, however it is of note that they hold the same businessIDs (bid) in each. It is just a change of what the value is for each key:value pair.

```
def crossMatch(TbidMap) :
    for Tbid in TbidMap :
        for Lbid in LbidMap :
            # Ensure T and L aren't the same business
            if Tbid != Lbid :
                # Get numer of reviews at EACH STAR rate for L
                for stars in LbidMap[Lbid] :
                    posTbid = 0;
                    # For each review check if user rated the Tbid
                    for Lreview in LbidMap[Lbid][stars] :
                        user = reviewMap[Lreview]['user'];
                        if user in TbidMap[Tbid] :
                            # user rev'd Tbid, get their Trid & see if gave Tbid pos rev
                            for Trid in TbidMap[Tbid][user] :
                                Tstar = reviewMap[Trid]['stars'];
                                if Tstar in pos_list :
                                    posTbid += 1;
                    #probability calculations happen here
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and output data? You used `if BusinessA != BusinessB :` what are these?

Comment: businessA, BusinessB are unique businesses within a dictionary of businesses such that businessA is not BusinessB (e.g., McDonalds is not Wendy's).

Comment: Do you hold `business` in memory? How do you store the results?

Comment: `business` is a dict originally read from JSON objects in memory. 
Results are stored in a separate dict essentially of form `results[business] = result`

Comment: This shouldn't fill the memory. You are not really adding information. You are just looping.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen : When I ran a version of the above algorithm, I started it on Friday hoping it would be resolved today. Instead it got killed after running for 78859.62 sec (~22hr) where it got to #8007 for `BusinessA` and #32961 for `BusinessB`

Comment: @Alison `businessA` is not `BusinessA` and `businessB` is not `BusinessB`, right?

Comment: OK, that's not necessarily a memory issue. Perhaps you just hit the CPU wall time. Is this a list or a set or a dictionary? `business[BusinessA]['users']`. List lookups are O(n). Set lookups are O(1).

Comment: You are currently evaluating all off-diagonal elements of a square. You only need to evaluate the upper triangle, right? Use enumerate and check that the A index is greater than the B index or vice versa. That will reduce your run time by a factor 2.

Comment: @vishes_shell - oh god, just realizing I used capitalization mid-way through typing question. All vars should be lowercase (so BusinessA should be businessA). I'll edit.

@tommy.carstensen - `business[businessA]['users']` is a dictionary with value 'users' that is a list... does that make sense?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - I am not sure what you're asking. It might help to know the scope of what I am trying to identify, "a sum of positive reviews given to a `businessA` for each star rating (1 - 5) `review` to a `businessB`".


Identification of positive reviews is found in the inner-most for-loop.

Comment: What is "do something"? If you're trying every combination, then effectively you would have 5,935,007,000-ish combinations. That's quite a bit of data if this is all in memory...

Comment: In other words, you have to dump something in "do something" and I assume you're trying to aggregate it instead in some kind of in-memory object. Even SQLite should be fine to hold all the combinations, you just need an `INSERT` somewhere in the innermost loops and clear whatever object you're using to store the data for the next iteration.

Comment: @roganjosh - it is an aggregation at "do something" with calculation of probability. The maximum number of elements stored as results is 77,039 keys (the number of businesses)

Comment: @Alison if I understand correctly: not true. It's 77,039*77,038. You have a nested loop. Every business is checked against every other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125434/discussion-between-alison-and-roganjosh).

Comment: @Alison could you try running your code like `python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] myscript.py`, where sort_order is cumtime? That will show you, which parts of your code is slow. Run it on a smaller dataset; e.g. break the loop after the first 100-1000 entries.

Answer (score 2):

There are over 5 billion combinations of companies in your dataset, which is really going to stress the memory out. I think you're storing all results into memory; instead, I would do interim dumps to a database and free up your containers. This is a sketch of the approach as I have no real data to test on, and it might be easier to respond to your difficulties as you encounter them. Ideally there would be an interim container for nested lists so that you could use `executemany` but this is so heavily nested with abbreviated names and no test data that it's difficult to follow.

```
import sqlite3

def create_interim_mem_dump(cursor, connection):

    query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings(
            Tbid TEXT,
            Lbid TEXT,
            posTbid TEXT)
            """
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()


def crossMatch(TbidMap, cursor, connection) :
    for Tbid in TbidMap :
        for Lbid in LbidMap :
            # Ensure T and L aren't the same business
            if Tbid != Lbid :
                # Get numer of reviews at EACH STAR rate for L
                for stars in LbidMap[Lbid] :
                    posTbid = 0;
                    # For each review check if user rated the Tbid
                    for Lreview in LbidMap[Lbid][stars] :
                        user = reviewMap[Lreview]['user'];
                        if user in TbidMap[Tbid] :
                            # user rev'd Tbid, get their Trid & see if gave Tbid pos rev
                            for Trid in TbidMap[Tbid][user] :
                                Tstar = reviewMap[Trid]['stars'];
                                if Tstar in pos_list :
                                    posTbid += 1;   
                    query = """INSERT INTO ratings (Tbid, Lbid, posTbid) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?)"""
                    cursor.execute(query, (Tbid, Lbid, posTbid))
        connection.commit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = sqlite3.connect('collated_ratings.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    create_db = create_interim_mem_dump(c, conn)
    your_data = 'Some kind of dictionary into crossMatch()'
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```